# Как сделать возможность переключения стиля сайта asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Хочу сделать переключение темы сайта с темной на светлую, как на [professorweb](https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level1/infocsharp.php) (там слева вторая кнопка сверху). Как такое можно провернуть?

Comment: Там в куки записывается некоторая переменная. На сервере проверять если в куках установлено значение, то возвращаем одни стили, если не установлено - другое.

Comment: мне так сложно не надо (с куками). Мне достаточно чтобы по дефолту он был  светлым, а если пользователю хочется он жмёт на кнопку и в течении его сеанса сайт тёмный. Это для начала. а потом уже с куками разбираться буду)

Comment: куки это наиболее простой путь. Вам при подключении css файлов, надо знать какой файл подключать со светлыми или темными цветами. Чтобы знать что подключать, надо где то хранить флаг выбора. И хранить его надо либо в куки либо в сессии. на упомянутом сайте в куках для светлой темы передается значение `theme=1`

Comment: а как мне записывать в куки? через jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем за ответы. Разобрался сам сделал так:

1. Создал 2 стиля сайта (тёмный и светлый).
2. Создал кнопку вызова Контроллера по записи в куки смены темы
3. Собственно сам контроллер:

   ```
   public ActionResult ChangeTheme()
   {
       if(Request.Cookies["theme"].Value == null)
       {
           Response.Cookies["theme"].Value = "dark";
       }
       else
       {
           if (Request.Cookies["theme"].Value == "dark")
           {
               Response.Cookies["theme"].Value = "light";
           }
           else if (Request.Cookies["theme"].Value == "light")
           {
               Response.Cookies["theme"].Value = "dark";
           }
       }

       return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
   ```
4. И в _Layout в head написал такой код:

   ```
   if (Request.Cookies["theme"] == null)
   {
       <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   }
   else
   {
       if (Request.Cookies["theme"].Value == "dark")
       {
           <link href="~/Content/Site2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
       }
       if (Request.Cookies["theme"].Value == "light")
       {
           <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
       }
   }
   ```

   Всё работает как часы. Всем еще раз спасибо